# Using gsub across columns

Tags: r, gsub

I have some data:

```
testData <- tibble(fname = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Dan", "Eric"), 
lname = c("Smith", "West", "CharlieBlack", "DanMcDowell", "Bush"))
```

A few of the last names have first names concatenated to them.

What is an effective way to go through and fix the `lname` column?

I want it to look like this:

```
lname = c("Smith", "West", "Black", "McDowell", "Bush")
```

I can use a `for` loop but I have half a million rows of data so I'd like to find a more efficient method.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_remove`

```
library(tidyverse)
testData %>%
   mutate(lname = str_remove(lname, fname))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  fname   lname   
#  <chr>   <chr>   
#1 Alice   Smith   
#2 Bob     West    
#3 Charlie Black   
#4 Dan     McDowell
#5 Eric    Bush
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gsub` within `apply`:

```
apply(testData,1,function(x) gsub(x['fname'],"",x['lname']))
```

Output:

```
[1] "Smith"    "West"     "Black"    "McDowell" "Bush"
```

Answer (score 0):

try `mutate` with an `ifelse` clause to catch the `lname` entires that are concatenated, e.g.:

`library(dplyr)
testData <- testData %>% mutate(lname = ifelse(grepl('[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+[[:upper:]]', lname), gsub('^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+', "", lname), lname))`

In this example, you are saying "mutate `lname` IF the string has 
an uppercase letter + at least one lowercase letter + an uppercase letter. If that condition is met, replace the first uppercase letter and following lowercase letters with nothing. If that condition is not met, just keep the original `lname` text".